# Whacky latin1 to UTF8 conversion in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, groovy, utf-8

JDBC seems to insert a utf8 replacement character when asked to read from a latin1 column containing undefined latin1 codepage characters. This behaviour is different from what MySQL's internal functions do.

Character encoding is a rabbit hole that i've been stuck in for the last week, and in interest of not generating 100 obvious answers i'll demonstrate whats happening with a couple of code examples.

Mysql:

```
[admin@yarekt ~]$ echo 'SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX("81") using latin1);' | mysql --init-command='set names latin1' | tail -1| hexdump -C
00000000  81 0a                                             |..|
00000002
[admin@yarekt ~]$ echo 'SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX("81") using latin1);' | mysql --init-command='set names utf8' | tail -1| hexdump -C
00000000  c2 81 0a                                          |...|
00000003
```

This is pretty obvious and works exactly as expected. `0x81` is an undefined latin1 codepoint. It is represented as `\u0081` in UTF8 or `c2 81` in hex "on disk".

Now the weirdness comes from `JDBC`, Take this groovy example:

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.6')
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/test', 'root', '', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' )
sql.eachRow( 'SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX("C281") using utf8) as a;' ) { println "$it.a --" }
```

The output of this query is two bytes, `c2 81` as expected. Its pretty easy to understand whats happening here. The Mysql Connection is defaulting to UTF8. The unhexxed column is also cast to UTF8 (without encoding, as the source is binary, the data after CONVERT() is still `c2 81`).

Now consider this case. The connection is still in UTF8, as is default with JDBC. we cast our 0x81 byte as latin1, so hopefully mysql will convert it to `c2 81` like it did in the bash example above.

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.6')
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance( 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/test', 'root', '', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' )
sql.eachRow( 'SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX("81") using latin1) as a;' ) { println "$it.a --" }
```

Running this with `groovy latin1_test.groovy | hexdump -C` yields this:

```
00000000  ef bf bd 0a                                       |....|
00000004
```

`ef bf bd` is a utf8 replacement char. A char used when a utf8 conversion has failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JDBC seems to insert a utf8 replacement character when asked to read from a latin1 column containing undefined latin1 codepage characters

Yes, this is the default behavior of [`CharsetDecoder` instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) which by default, [when the (byte) input is malformed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput-java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction-), will perform a [substitution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPLACE) of this unmappable byte sequence with [Unicode's replacement character, U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Examples of methods which use this behavior are all `Reader`s but also `String` constructors which take a byte array as an argument. And this is the reason why you should never use `String` to store binary data!

The only solution to make that an error is to grab the raw byte input, create your own decoder and tell it to [fail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html#REPORT) in that situation...

Comment: Why is Java doing the charset conversion, when mysql can do it with set names utf8?. I unfortunately don't have access to the Java code here (the groovy is just for testing), as the problem comes from Sqoop, a mysql to hadoop import application

Comment: Well, you ask to print the content, therefore it has to do the decoding, right?

Comment: Could the data be printed in binary (or whatever makes it being not modified/converted). Its just that, c2 81 is a valid UTF8 codepoint, and mysql converts any latin1 codepoint (00 to FF) to a U+0000 to U+00FF, which may be wrong, but at least its reversible

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help further; I have dropped MySQL for a veeery long time in favor of PostgreSQL...